# GDM3 and GDM don't start in Ubuntu 20.04 - Kernel 5.11.0-34-generic - Nvidia Driver 470

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, gdm

I hope you can help me, as the title says and gdm3 starts on a black screen, I restart the PC and both gdm start correctly, I have configured the nomodeset grub and tried everything found on the internet.

when I login in command mode I restart gdm3 and it works.

any help, tip & tricks are welcome and greatly appreciated.

I stay tuned and I wait for you.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't work, in the end I disabled the start with graphic interface and started everything manually

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing the same problem and the solution is:-

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

This will ask you to select your display manager and there you can choose GDM3.